# Opening A Website in app Android Studio

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to open a website in app and I code this.

```
ara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent niyet=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("www.google.com"));
startActivity(niyet);
```

App starts and when I a push the ara button app stops working and I get this error.  "No Activity Found to Handle Intent"

Comment: Why don't you use WebView to this situation?

Comment: You need to add `http://`or `https://` to the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give Valid URI `http://` or `https://` like bellow

```
https://www.google.com
```

if you want to do it in app then use webview for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use webview to load a url inside your activity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebview ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mWebview  = new WebView(this);

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

        final Activity activity = this;

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mWebview .loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        setContentView(mWebview );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, It will open the website in your application's page.

```
    Intent Browse = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://YOUR WEB SITE NAME"));
    startActivity(Browse);
```